# Svg icon causes adjacent elements to change their positions

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg

I am currently building a navigation bar with React. I want to use an svg icon on which the user can click and see details regarding their profile. When adding it next to the other elements of the navigation bar however, it causes them to change their positions.

NavBar.js

```
  <nav className={NavBarStyles.nav_bar}>
    <h1 className={NavBarStyles.logo}>Tirbu&Son</h1>
    <div className={NavBarStyles.options_list}>
      <h5>Music</h5>
      <h5>Clothing</h5>
      <div className={NavBarStyles.icon}></div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

NavBar.css

```
.nav_bar {
  /* dimensions */
  width: 100vw;
  height: 3rem;

  /* colors */
  background: black;
  color: white;

  /* flex */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.options_list h5 {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0.75rem 1rem;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url("../../../assets/icons/account-profile.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can update `NavBar.css` with this:

```
.options_list {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url("../../../assets/icons/account-profile.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
}
```